# How can i fully clear previous data of an app on iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I want to clear all data of an iOS app, I have tried to do following steps,

1. uninstall it
2. clear iCloud data
3. deleted some keys about it from keychain** (my iphone has jailbreaked, I use keychianeditor to do this, and I traced it by Snoop-it and I am sure that is no more data read from keychain)
4. clear GameCenter data
5. I reinstall it with other apple id from appStore

   but the app always can restore before device id, I have no idea how it can identify the phone.

Comment: It obviously uses magic.

Comment: What's your software development question here?